# Return const reference to array of char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Ok, so this is my first post and/or question, and this is for a project so I'm totally ok with an overly educational answer.

I have an array of char arrays which has been declared as follows:

```
CharArray *m_CharArrayArray;
```

The only function I cannot get to compile (from the abstract class provided) goes like:

```
virtual CharArray * const &at(size_t index) const = 0;
```

I have gotten the following function to compile and am attempting to edit the working model...

```
virtual CharArray * const &at(size_t index) const {
return m_CharArrayArray;
};
```

I have tried multiple in line return values because my "iterator" is unusable in a const function. On an aside, If someone could elaborate on what the specific difference is between the const expressions before and after the function header that would be great!

```
return m_CharArrayArray + index;
```

yields

```
error: returning reference to temporary
```

and

```
return m_CharArrayArray[index];
```

yields

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘CharArray* const&’ from expression of type ‘CharArray’
```

I've also tried multiple other variations having pointer and reference symbols before the return value. So what am I missing here? I was thinking that returning a reference is just an address and adding the value of index to that address would yield the address of the desired CharArray.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `std::string` ?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @Mahesh Yes, the point of the assignment is familiarizing use with pointers and reference. We are also not allowed to use standard libraries that affect the data structure (but he recommended the memmove, so I have no rebuttal to that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the return type of your function.

```
virtual CharArray * const &at(size_t index) const = 0;
```

It returns this type:

```
CharArray * const &
```

Reading that type out loud requires you to scan it right-to-left.

> **reference** to a **const pointer** to `CharArray`

That's two levels of indirection, right?  *something to something-else to something-else*.

Here's your problem.

```
return m_CharArrayArray + index;
```

That addition operation creates a new temporary pointer.  And you're then returning a reference to that temporary.  And if you search the web for "[returning a reference to a temporary](https://www.google.com/search?q=returning%20a%20reference%20to%20a%20temporary)"... wow.

As it turns out, your reference isn't just the source of your error.  It was never needed.

```
virtual CharArray * const at(size_t index) const = 0;
```

That will work fine.

Comment: Agree, and `m_CharArrayArray[index];` has type `CharArray`, instead of `CharArray*`.

Comment: @imlyc *just a reference* would be good in that case.  *Just a pointer* with pointer math.  But not both.

Comment: If the following is true